# How to verify an email before making it the primary (Firebase Authentication)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In firebase auth I am able to verify a users email only after I have made it their primary email for logging in.
I can change the users email this way:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateEmail("user@example.com").then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Then I can verify the email after it has been set this way:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
  // Email sent.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

What I want to do is verify the email BEFORE it is set to the users primary email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, you have the ability to change the email only after it is verified. The API is not well documented. You can do it via [verifyBeforeUpdateEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#verifybeforeupdateemail).

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail('newEmail@example.com')
  .then(function() {
    // Verification email sent.
    /  When the user clicks the email link,
    // it will update to newEmail@example.com and set it as verified,
    // emailVerified: true.
    // Until then, the old email remains on the account.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Error occurred. Inspect error.code.
  });
```

Comment: This looks like an awesome solution but I am getting this error every time: _TypeError: firebase.auth(...).currentUser.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail is not a function_

Comment: And I believe I am importing correctly since I am able to get the currentUser, it just doesnt seem to have the function verifyBeforeUpdateEmail

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the SDK? This was added recently.

Comment: Yes that was it. Updated to Firebase 7.14.2. Awesome solution this is even better than what I was hoping for.

Comment: @bojeil The docs for generating email verification links (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links) state: "The email used must belong to an existing user." This seems to imply we cannot combine generated email verification links with verification before update. Is that right?

Comment: Looks like that is the case, as the API currently returns: `USER_NOT_FOUND` and does not have any option to specify the uid of an existing user along with the new email to be verified.

Answer (score 0):

Chipping in from April 2023, firebase 9.9.0 (angular/fire 7.4.1), this seems to work for me on my Angular project. I can:

1. login with Phone authentication, currentUser is as expected:

```json
email: null,
phoneNumber: "+47987654321"
```

2. call verifyBeforeUpdateEmail() with some email -> I get a mail with an email link, click it, get the message I can now login. Login and currentUser is as expected:

```json
email: "email+blabla@gmail.com",
phoneNumber: "+47987654321",
providerData: [
  {providerid:"phone" …},
  {
    providerid:"password" // yeah it's password also for passwordless :)
    email: "email+blabla@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

3. call verifyBeforeUpdateEmail() with some OTHER email -> I get a mail with an email link, click it, get the message I can now login. Login and currentUser is as expected:

```json
email: "email+otherbla@gmail.com",
phoneNumber: "+47987654321",
providerData: [
 {providerid:"phone" …},
 {
   providerid:"password",
   email: "email+otherbla@gmail.com"
 }
]
```

…annnd there's still exactly two entries to providerData, but there's no trace of the original `email+blabla@gmail.com` in the currentUser anymore.

-- Unless I misunderstood this thread I think it now works :) Anyway, it put me on the right track, so thanks!